# SharedPreferences in Android dosent work

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I created a sharedprefreference object and tries to retrieve my data within the same activity, is that an allowed operation? The issue is that once the application starts running, and i entered the text within the textview, the entered text does not reappear in a separate textview. The application suppose to take in the user's entered text and display is just several dp downward, however, the entered text just never reappeared. Thank you all so much in advance.

```
    final static String My_PREFERENCES= "sharedPreferences";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    foodTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodTV);
    foodET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.foodET);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            getSharedPreferences(My_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
    edit.clear();
    edit.putString("foodname", foodET.getText().toString());
    edit.commit();

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(My_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String food = sharedPreferences.getString("foodname", "");
            display.setText(food);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is your issue pls be clear

Comment: if you use `edit.putString("foodname", foodET.getText().toString());` in your `onCreate()`, an empty string would be stored in the shared preference as there is nothing inside the `EditText` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Move this code SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();     edit.clear();     edit.putString("foodname", foodET.getText().toString());     edit.commit();   Inside your button onclick listener

Comment: I've mode the code into the onclick listener @SaravInfern, and it worked! Thank you! but how come that worked? what is the reasoning behind?

Comment: as stated by @Lal above `edit.putString("foodname", foodET.getText().toString());` is  in your onCreate() which saves the value of edittext (which is empty during oncreate) in shared preference once during creation of your activity. Now you have moved the code inside the button onclick the value of edit text is stored inside share preference every time you click the button and fetched back within onclick

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
foodTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodTV);
foodET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.foodET);
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);

  foodET.setOnEditorActionListener(
              new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,KeyEvent event) {
                     if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                           actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                         event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                         event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
    if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
        getSharedPreferences(My_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.putString("foodname", foodET.getText().toString());
        edit.commit();
       return true; 
      }                
       }
        return false; 
     }
      });

 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
             SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =    getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(My_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         String food = sharedPreferences.getString("foodname", "");
        display.setText(food);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please point out clearly what is the difference between your snippet and the OP's snippet, and how it should solve the problem.

Comment: your are saving the value in sharedpreference initially when there is no text in edit text foodET. i am saving text of foodET in shared preference once you done typing.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I would suggest you using an amazing https://github.com/pilgr/Paper

## See how's simple is that:

Only two things are needed:

1. Initialize library inside your app (or even Activity itself) class
2. Make calls!

### MyApp.java

Just initialize Paper

```
Paper.init(getApplicationContext());
```

### MyFragment.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Sample food name
    String foodName = "apple";

    // Write it to paper
    Paper.book().write("foodname", foodName);

    // Then restore what we have just saved!
    String restoredFoodName = Paper.book().read("foodname");
}
```

**Please do note that those calls are not asynchronous! But you can write few simple AsyncTask-s to make them be so.**